# In cold weather, sensor on garage door opener malfunctions

Tags: sensor

I have an electronics question, I hope this is an appropriate forum. I have an electric garage door opener. It works just fine in the summer, but when the weather gets cooler (not below freezing, I live in Australia) something funny happens. I press the button to open it, it opens about a foot and a half then stops, and starts going down again. I stop this by pressing the button again. Then I start it going again, and now it goes up to about 3 feet high, then stops and reverses again. I stop it, then press the button, then up to 4 1/2 feet or so, then stops and reverses again. But now when I press it it goes all the way up. My guess is that somehow the sensor gets messed up when it gets cool, but I have no idea why or how to fix it. Then again, I know nothing really about these things, so maybe my guess is wrong anyway. Has anyone seen something like this, and have any suggestions?

Greg

Comment: Honestly this is probably  MECHANICAL.   The door goes up until it senses a blockage, at which point it starts going down.   Could be simple as your door needs more grease.   Or the big spring that helps lift  the door may need to be tightened a little .  DONT TRY THAT YOURSELF.

Comment: there are also electrical possibilities such as broken sensor wires where break grows from shrinkage of the metal.  if you can test the sensor separately, you might be able to rule it out.

Answer (score 2):

In the USA, there are usually two "sensors". An optical sensor near the floor to detect obstructions and a motor current detector to sense force. You can usually adjust the force, but if you increase it you may defeat the safety mechanisms. Read your instruction manual carefully.

Most garage openers have a shuttle that rides on a rail. There should be an emergency handle to disconnect the door from the shuttle so you can open/close the door manually without power. With the shuttle disconnected, test the door for binding. It may only require lubrication.

The springs should balance the door such that only a small amount of force is necessary to open and close the door. If the springs are strongly pulling the door up or down, hire a professional to adjust them. This is not a DIY job, the tension is enormous and you can seriously injure yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As Kyle B wrote, the problem is probably of mechanical type, but I would distinguish two cases.

1. The garage opener is "native", i. e. the garage door had an integrated door opener, also the same company designed the garage door and its opener. The whole assembly functioned fine for months or years and now does not. In this case the problem may be given by mechanical damage of some part and may be fixed by a technician with a good knowledge of that product.
2. You had a hand operated garage door and you let it be "motorized" by adding a door opener kit with remote control. In this case the problem could be solved only by changing the whole kit with another one of a different brand (and sensitivity). Some door openers are very sensitive to mechanical loads because they are designed to protect people or pets on the closing path. Some garage doors are not well balanced and their opening or closing path require a quite variable force, which may be perceived by the security sensors of the mechanism as an "obstacle" to be protected. In this case, if the "force setting" doesn't work properly, the only solution is to change the opening door kit with another one of less sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for these answers. Of course, now that you all have mentioned it, probably it's not a sensor but rather that the door is meeting some resistance and is closing for that reason. Maybe it needs to be greased up a bit, I'll give that a shot. Thanks!

Greg